# How to implement onClick componentDidMount() in React using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to make a movie search function using React, Axios, and movieDB API. The functionality I am trying to implement right now is typing in a movie into the search bar and clicking the submit button will return the movie title as an H1 element.

My onClick function does not work: `<button onClick={(e)=>clickHandler()}>submit</button>`

componentDidMount() will work only when the page refreshes and you cannot search for anything as the submit button is broken.

I am not sure how to implement this, but I would also not mind if I could get it to search by hitting enter instead of using a button, whichever is easier.

Here is my code so far.

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import Movielist from './components/Movielist'



function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="search" id="search" />
            <button onClick={(e)=>clickHandler()}>submit</button>
            <h1 id="title">title</h1>
            <Movielist />
        </div>

    )
}

export default App
```

Movielist.js

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Movielist extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: ""
  }

    componentDidMount() {
    const API_KEY = '***********************';
    const query = document.getElementById('search').value;
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {
        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

      })

  }

  render() {
    return (

    <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>

    )
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Movielist extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: ""
  }

    clickHandler = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           const query = event.target.value;
           const API_KEY = '***********************';
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {
        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

      })
        }
    }

  render() {
    return (

<input type="search" id="search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />
    <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error  ./src/App.js
  Line 10:35:  'clickHandler' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: ```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export class App extends React.Component {
  clickHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
       const query = event.target.value;
       const API_KEY = '***********************';
        console.log(event.target.value)
    }
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="search" id="search" onKeyDown={this.clickHandler} />
    );
  }
}

```

Comment: This is only putting what I write in the text box into the console not getting the title of the movie from the API and returning it as an h1 element

Comment: I gave an example. You need to implement axios like you did earlier.

Comment: @JSheckle You replace console.log(event.target.value) with ``` const query = event.target.value;
           const API_KEY = '***********************';
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {
        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

      }) ```

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but that is returning this after I search for something```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this is undefined
clickHandler/<
D:/Web Development/React Projects/moviesearch/src/App.js:16```

Comment: Not a problem, I have updated my original answer. Try it.

Comment: This final version works perfectly, thank you for your troubles.

Comment: @JSheckle Glad to help you friend.

Comment: One last thing, I am curious of this one line ```if (event.keyCode === 13) ``` why the number 13?

Comment: keyCode for enter key is 13

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query the API after user push submit button. You should put your call to API in the call handler, then pass the state from App to MovieList as props

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        title: ""
    }

    clickHandler() {
        const API_KEY = '***********************';
        const query = document.getElementById('search').value;
        axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`).then(res => {
            const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
            this.setState({ title });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="search" id="search" />
                <button onClick={(e)=>clickHandler()}>submit</button>
                <h1 id="title">title</h1>
                <Movielist list={this.state.title}/>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export class MovieList extends React.Component {
    render() {
         <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the input in a  element and use onSubmit + evt.preventDefault() instead, by doing so you can handle button click and pressing "Enter" to submit.

Comment: I am getting error: ```./src/App.js
  Line 28:1:  Parsing error: Only one default export allowed per module.```

Comment: It is because I put both script that is suppose to be in 2 different files into a single script block. If you wants to put MovieList and App into the same file, you need to remove one or both `default` from `export default class App` and `export default class MovieList`, depending on how your project files is structured.

Answer (score 0):

You should call API to get the movie list after hitting the button, then pass the data that you've got to `Movielist`. Try this:
In `App.js`:

```js
import React from "react"
import axios from 'axios'
import Movielist from './components/Movielist'

function App() {
    const [movieList, setMovieList] = React.useState([])
    const handleOnSubmit = () => {
      const API_KEY = '***********************';
      const query = document.getElementById('search').value;
      axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
        .then(res => {
          const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
          setMovieList(res.data['results'])
        })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="search" id="search" />
            <button onClick={handleOnSubmit}>submit</button>
            <h1 id="title">title</h1>
            <Movielist movieList={movieList}/>
        </div>

    )
}

export default App
```

In `Movielist.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Movielist = ({movieList}) => {
    return (
    <div>
      {
        movieList.map(movie => <h1 key={movie.key}>{movie.title}</h1>)
      }
    <div/>
    )
  }
}

export default Movielist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import axios from 'axios';
import Movielist from './components/Movielist'

const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
const API_KEY = '***********************'

function App() {

  const clickHandler = () => {
    const query = document.getElementById('search').value;
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
    .then(res => {
      const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
      setTitle(title);
    })

 }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="search" id="search" />
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>submit</button>
            <h1 id="title">title</h1>
            <Movielist title={title} />
        </div>

    )
}

export default App
```

just move call api handle to your onclik func then pass title props to movie list

Comment: I am getting an error saying ```./src/App.js
  Line 10:35:  'clickHandler' is not defined  no-undef ``` and when I try to add the import into App.js like this import React from "react"
import Movielist from './components/Movielist'
import clickHandler from './components/Movielist'  it returns the error ```./src/components/Movielist.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Movielist' in 'D:\Web Development\React Projects\moviesearch\src\components'```

Comment: try to move const clickHandler = () => ....
in to your App func
sr for that :D

Comment: Do I put that under function App()?

Comment: Sorry about that, I had mistaken my App.js code for Movielist.js. But now that I changed that the error I am getting is ```Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks```

Comment: oh this is because your App is func component , and your movie list is class component. Try to swicth movie list to func component. hook feature only run in func component :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215555/discussion-between-jsheckle-and-anh-tuan).